# Recorrer arreglo en php

Tags: php

quisiera recorrer un arreglo pero solo quiero un solo campo que en este caso seria "status". Que imprima en pantalla la palabra abierto. Ayuda porfavor!

Este es el arreglo:

```
{
    "status": "Abierto",
    "last_author": "56935387022"
}
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api-cluster.postcenter.io/v2/ticket/5d9b5a86b2a7d10db4a05935/',
                 CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> TRUE,
                 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    'Authorization: Key 76e7e6402ed09e3def8e09eaba1d94ea46985e4b24c6a3a422b42c06aabb1f232d6e9beb814531d233abc2564393330606e68be35987470e60a746adbe9bb117',
                    "cache-control: no-cache"
                )
                );

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$r=curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$r)
    {
        $mData=array( curl_error($ch) );

    } else {
        $json=json_decode($r);
        $mData=$json;
    }

    curl_close($ch);


foreach ($mData as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

Comment: Ya probaste con `echo $item['status'];`?

Comment: La variable `$mData` es un objeto, por lo que lo correcto sería `echo $mData->status;`

Comment: @alanfcm Warning: Illegal string offset 'status' in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\API\variable.php on line 42. Me aparece ese error.

Comment: @Marcos aparece este error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\API\variable.php on line 41

Comment: @YerckoOrtega, simplemente borra el `foreach` y haz `echo $mData->status;`

Comment: @Marcos hay me funciono me habia equivocado, inserte en mi codigo otra variable, ahi me funciono. Gracias crack denuevo,

Comment: @Marcos solo un apunte, si que puedes iterar un objeto con foreach, de hecho lo dice en la segunda frase de la documentacion: _foreach funciona sólo sobre arrays_ __y objetos__ https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @Xerif, gracias por el apunte, estaba equivocado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creo que tienes una confusión entre lo que es un objeto JSON y un arreglo JSON.

Esto es un objeto JSON:

```
{
    "status": "Abierto",
    "last_author": "56935387022"
}
```

No es un arreglo. Si fuese un arreglo empezaría con `[` y terminaría con `]`. Es una diferencia importante que es preciso comprender cuando trabajas con respuestas JSON que provienen de cURL o de APIs u otras.

En consecuencia, puedes leer los datos directamente, así: `$json->status`.

Veamos una prueba:

```
$r=
    '
{
    "status": "Abierto",
    "last_author": "56935387022"
}
    ';
$json=json_decode($r);
echo $json->status;
```

**Salida:**

```
Abierto
```

Veamos un ejemplo de un arreglo JSON (observa cómo empieza y cómo termina).

```
$r=
    '
    [
{
    "status": "Abierto",
    "last_author": "56935387022"
},
{
    "status": "Cerrado",
    "last_author": "56935387023"
}
    ]
    ';
$json=json_decode($r);
```

Aquí puedes leer dentro de un bucle, sin importar que sea un arreglo de objetos:

```
foreach ($json as $item){
    echo $item->status.PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Abierto
Cerrado
```

O bien puedes acceder directamente usando el índice:

```
echo $json[0]->status;
```

**Salida:**

```
Abierto
```

Comment: y si quiero recorrer parametros dentro de otro parametro como por ejemplo si quiero obtener el dato de name?: 
    `{
    "current_assignment": {
        "email": null,
        "name": "Josselyn Rojas",
        "cmid": 3257
    }
    }`

Comment: @YerckoOrtega sería tan simple como `$tuObjeto->current_assignment->name` La lectura de un JSON es simplísima, sólo que los programadores de SO en español tienen la costumbre de recomiendar mucho que el JSON se convierta a array, complicando las cosas. Lo importante es que conozcas el JSON, su estructura, y sepas diferenciar cuándo es un objeto JSON `{ ... }` y cuando es un un array JSON `[ {...}, {...}]`

Comment: `$var16 = $mData2->last_assignment->name; ` he seguido tu ejemplo y no me funciona intente hacerlo con un foreach dentro de otro foreach y no logro tampoco hacerlo, me resulta raro. Me da error  `Trying to get property of non-object `.

Comment: @YerckoOrtega hay que ver el JSON completo para poder decirte la forma de leerlo. Quizá sea mejor que plantees esa nueva dificultad en otra pregunta. De todos modos, en el otro comentario la clave se llama `current_assignment` y aquí presentas otra clave que es `last_assignment`. Es muy fácil analizar un JSON, muéstralo en otra pregunta y así podremos darte algunos matices para tratar los JSON.

Comment: ahí me funciono yo tenia un error que no me había dado cuenta. Gracias!!

Comment: Sería bueno comentar en la respuesta que el segundo parámetro de `json_decode` hace que lo que se retorne sea un array asociativo, permitiendo que el código del OP funcione si lo plantea como `foreach ($mData as $key => $item) {`